# Laravel passport refresh token with same response

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-passport, refresh-token

I am using laravel passport for authentication in APIs for my website,
My project is single-page and multiple api are called simultaneously.If the token expires and then the page refresh,We have several simultaneous requests to refresh the token.

1. All of these requests have the same parameter value(current `refreshToken`)
2. Output result for all requests must be the same

> by Receiving response from the first request: The `refreshToken` for other requests is invalid,Because it will be revoked in the database

To avoid this error, I store the first response in the Cache and in the next requests for this `refreshToken` I read the output value from Cache

But sometimes, before the value is written to the cache, the next request arrives and fails

Do you have a solution for me? Regardless of the way I've used it

Comment: "We have several simultaneous requests to refresh the token". I suggest doing this call to refresh the token once. With the constraint of several simultaneous requests to refresh the token, the cache layer will be  have a more complex caching strategy to manage the token in the application. This will involve doing checks to see if the refresh token was updated in the cache before updating it.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule Do you also suggest using cache to fix my problem?

Comment: no, I don't suggest using the cache for this. I suggest the earlier approach of doing a single call to refresh the token.